# Ошибка JS в phpstorm

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpstorm

Возникла странная проблема, при написании сайта... При создании яваскрипта в phpstorm выдает такую наркоманию... Кто сталкивался?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, вместо скриншота приложите содержимое ошибки простым текстом, чтобы другие люди могли найти данный вопрос в поисковиках

Comment: у вас в Settings/Languages&Frameworks/Javascript/Code Quality Tools/ включена поддержка jshint, jscs и eslint. Вам нужно либо настроить эти инструменты, либо отключить их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто надо настроить PHPStorm. Он пытается проверить ваш код инструментами анализа, а они у вас не настроены. Конкретно эти настройки находятся File/Settings/Languages&Frameworks/Javascript/Code Quality Tools/